# Text file location and its data check at FTP server in informatica

Tags: informatica

How to check in informatica whether a flat file exists at a location at FTP server and to check if it has some data in it?

Comment: Yes. It has to be checked in workflow and if the file exists and it has some data then further session has to run else a mail has to be sent to some user.

Comment: Is the file existing in a remote location where you need to connect via FTP? Or is the file transferred (pushed) to a local location where Informatica has access?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create Windows or Unix shell script on the Informatica server that checks for the existence of the file. 
Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

if [ ! -f /Filelocation/INPUT_FILENAME.txt]
  then
    echo "Source not found"  
    exit 1
  else
       echo "Source present"     
          exit 0
  fi
done
exit 1
```

Create a command session in Workflow that runs this script.